# Capistrano guides?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

Does anyone know of any good, detailed guides for capistrano and deploying rails applications? I'm interested in learning all the different functionality rather than just following a tutorial without really understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Github made the [great tutorial](http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/) howto setup capistrano.

Comment: Github's tutorial wasn't much of help

Answer (score 1):

You can reference to the [Capistrano Handbook](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-From-The-Beginning) and [Getting start](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Getting-Started) guide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it could be what you are looking for, but I just wrote how to make Rails 3.2, Nginx and Capistrano work  http://www.lifeofadev.eu/posts/deploy-rails-3-2-with-capistrano

Comment: Thanks for sharing the blog, good stuff! How did you create the database? I'm trying to understand why the Capistrano documentation says I should do that manually rather than with rake db:create, which could be run by a Capistrano task.

Comment: Thanks :)
Anyway, the creation of db must be done only the first time. Why do you want to do it in every deployment?

Comment: You're right, I can manually run rake db:create on the deployment host, which would still be database-independent and easier than using MySQL tools directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this one, that at some point I might move off this gist:

https://gist.github.com/2161449

I agree there is/was a lack. I figured stuff out painfully, and then tried to write it up in a guide for others (and myself to refer back to)